# Open selection for mail client with React Native Linking API

Tags: javascript, react-native, email, react-native-linking

With `Linking` API in React Native, we can do something like that:

```
Linking.openURL(`mailto:${receiverEmail}`);
```

But, with this approach, the React Native app will open default mail client app instantly (e.g: Gmail), what I want to do is instead of open default mail client app, a pop up should come from bottom of the app (like `Share` API in React Native does) and let user chooses from various of mail clients in their device.

Is there anyway to do it ? I really appreciate it, even, a suggestion.

Thanks in advance.